# Jquery/Js - Strip out text from URL

Tags: jquery

Here is my url:

```
https://sub.domain.com/core/subsite/piano/page/...
```

I need to take the string `'piano'`, and then apply it to elements on the page. **The string will not always be 'piano', i need to take the 3rd section of the URL.**

(Below is what I currently have which uses the breadcrumb of the page to identify what page the users is currently viewing) however I'd like to take `'piano'` as the class to apply:

```
$(function() {
    $('span .breadcrumb').each(function(){
        $('#Nav').addClass($(this).text());
        $('#Content').addClass($(this).text());
        $('.xpanding_footer').addClass($(this).text())
        $('#footer').addClass($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: by which criteria do you specify that it is 'piano' that you want to fetch? always first parameter that follows "subsite"? always third parameter? always second-to-last parameter? always the occurrence of "piano" if it exists, otherwise "not-piano"?

Comment: Are you asking about "third" part from url? If yes, you can get window.location.pathname.split('/')[3]

Comment: Yes the 3rd part please, its not always 'piano'

Comment: What is in the element that has class `breadcrumb` ?

Comment: The part that reads breadcrumb needs to be removed, .addClass($(this).text(); needs to be the 3rd part of the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess that you are asking about third parameter in pathname when you are splitting using backslash.

So, you can get the value using:

```
window.location.pathname.split('/')[3]
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how I might go about using this, some kind of example would be appreciated.

Comment: `window.location.pathname` is your url, excluding host name: `/core/subsite/piano/page/`. `split('/')` divides a string into an array, where the `/` is the delimiter for each new array position; thus: `["","core","subsite","piano","page",""]`. The `[3]` is accessing the fourth position (first pos being `[0]`) within that array, i.e. `piano`, and from there, you can store that as a variable, and do whatever you want with it.